# How to spy a function with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have some separate functions that I'm calling inside my main function. How can I spy those functions with Jest?

I have a function like this:

```
const insertRecord = async (image) => {
   const record = new Branch(image)
   await record.save()
}

const deleteRecord = async (image) => {
   const record = new Branch(image)
   await record.delete()
}

export const main = async (event, image) => {
   if (event === insert) insertRecord(image)
   if (event === delete) deleteRecord(image)
}
```

I have another file with tests and I import main function.

I'm trying to test if the main function calls insertRecord with correct params, how do I do that?

Comment: You don't - those functions aren't part of the public API, they're *implementation details*. Test the interactions with collaborators instead, in this case the `Branch`. But that's made more difficult by the fact you `new` it up, so read up on dependency inversion.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i gonna change the implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if i export others functions, and import in test arquive... can i spy them?

Comment: Jest offers extensive mocking capabilities, see e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions. But you should only use test doubles for *collaborators*; if `main` is using other functions in the same module, which again is an *implementation detail*, you can't and shouldn't be mocking those functions.